# shell_exec does not work on the server

Tags: php

I am trying to run a shell_exec command in my php script. When I use the same command on the virtual machine to test my code, it runs just fine, but when I transfer the same code on my server, it does not. The virtual machine I use is just the copy of the server, which I use to test my code before integrating it on my main machine. I have even double checked the permissions given to the files, and they are all the same.

Code Snippet of the Php Script:

```
else if($_POST['processtype'] == "server"){
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

#--Fetching data from the Form
$fserverId = $_POST['serverId'];
$finsname = $_POST['insname'];
$fhost = $_POST['host'];
$fport = $_POST['port'];
$fproto = $_POST['proto'];
$fuserName = $_POST['userName'];
$fpassword = $_POST['password'];
$fkey = $_POST['key'];
$fcompanyName = $_POST['companyName'];
$fofficeAddress = $_POST['officeAddress'];
$fstate = $_POST['state'];
$fcountry = $_POST['country'];
$fladmin = $_POST['lAdmin'];
$fphone = $_POST['phone'];
$fmobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$femail = $_POST['email'];
$fdesignation = $_POST['designation'];
$frManager = $_POST['rManager'];

$data = " --serverId ".$fserverId." --name ".$finsname." --host ".$fhost." --port ".$fport." --proto ".$fproto." --username ".$fuserName." --password ".$fpassword." --key ".$fkey." --companyName ".$fcompanyName." --officeAddress ".$fofficeAddress." --state ".$fstate." --country ".$fcountry." --ladmin ".$fladmin." --phone ".$fphone." --mobile ".$fmobile." --email ".$femail." --designation ".$fdesignation." --rManager ".$frManager;

#--Parsing the data from PHPscript to CGI



#This is the part not working#
$output = shell_exec('python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/dscr.cgi' .$data);
#---------------#

echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
header("Location: firewalls.php");
}

}

 else {
        echo "Error calling page... :( <br>";
        echo "Warning content should be here for notifying endUser about direct access.";
```

Calling `$data` displays the data that i want to pass and the code gets executed without calling the `else` part in the bottom, but the `shell_exec` command does not work. I checked the `php.ini` file to check for `disabled_functions` but even that does not have `shell_exec`. How should I tackle this problem? Any direction to getting over it would be appreciated and Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try to run something more simple, whats the output of shell_exec("whoami 2>&1");?

Comment: As far as i can see you are working on a linux server. The available commands might depend on linux version, access rights and server provider.
Is php an available command if you connect via SSH? If yes, you should also try to call the php script from CLI. 
Please note that not all server provider give you access to all possible commands.

Comment: @2oppin the output of `shell_exec("whoami2>&1");` prints apache. Does that mean that the `shell_exec` is working fine?

Comment: @DevanshuMisra, exactly. try to add 2>&1 to the end of your command, maybe you'll see the reason why it's not executing

Comment: @2oppin i did, and it did not run on the server. no output was produced when i used it in the main machine. the above output i got was on my machine, not the main one.

Comment: do you have ssh access to your "main" machine, check if you can execute the command "whoami".   add to your core var_dump(ini_get("disable_functions"));, to ensure that you using correct php.ini

Comment: @2oppin it sure does have ssh access. i tried executing "whoami" but no output is printed. other than that, when i used `var_dump(ini_get("disable_functions"));` in the code and printed the output, it prints `string(0)""`

Comment: then pass any other command that have output in ssh console to shell_exec. "ls" for example.  output your command that you try to shell_execute, and check the output in the console

Comment: @2oppin my php script basically sends data to a CGI script that takes command line arguments which are then written into an XML file. When i try to input the arguments using the terminal/command line, it does get written, but when the same thing is being done through my php script with shell_exec, it does not work.

Comment: your php script basically try to run shell command, no matter if you setup python for CGI, you run it in a console, so I can't get what "input" you try to enter in a shell? simply echo 'python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/dscr.cgi' .$data; and run the output in a console.

Comment: just used `echo 'python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/dscr.cgi' .$data;` and it simply skips the whole thing and executes the else part where error is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem that persisted was the fact that there is a Linux Security module called [SE-Linux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)(Security-Enhanced Linux) was enforced on my machine which provides a mechanism for supporting access control security policies, like MAC. It does not allow commands like `shell_exec` be executed by users other than the ones who have the permission to, like `root user`.

To get the the status of SE-Linux type in your shell `sestatus` or `getenforced`. It has 3 modes:

1) Enforcing: SE-Linux policy is enforced. SE-Linux denies access based on SE-Linux policy rules.

2)Permissive: SE-Linux policy is not enforced. SE-Linux does not deny access, but denials are logged for actions that would have been denied if running in enforcing mode.

3)Disabled: SE-Linux is disabled.

Hope this helps others, who might get stuck because of this.